# Search multi array and create new array containing elements from original array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The array looks something like this:

```
$array = array(
  array(
    'Item' => array(47, 48, 46, 42),
    'ID' => 1,
  ),
  array(
    'Item' => array(29, 37, 46, 48),
    'ID' => 2,
  ),
  array(
    'Item' => array(33, 27, 18),
    'ID' => 3,
  ),
);
```

What I am trying to do is to search through the [Item] arrays and if there is a match, add the [ID] to a new array.

So, if I was looking for `46` then I would get the results back of ID's `1` and `2` in a simple array.

I'm sure this should be so simple, but I seem to have hit a complete mental block so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($yourArray as $v)
    if(in_array(46, $v["Item"]))
        $ids[] = $v["ID"];
```

Comment: I swear I tried that.... I knew it was simple!  Anyway, that works nicely, thankyou for putting me out of my missery!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach($array as $v) {
if(in_array(46, $v['Item'])
    $ids[] = $v['ID']; //array $ids will contain 1, 2..and so on.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using in_array()?

You can iterate over the array and check if your value is located in the Item array.  Something like:

```
function getId(array $array, $value) {
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($array as $element) {
       if (in_array($value, $element['Item'])) {
           $ids[] = $element['ID'];
       }
    }
    return $ids;
}
```